# Настройка WebHook Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

Доброго времени суток.
Собственно проблема в настройке **WebHook**

Пробовал настроить 2 способами:

- Сертификат привязан в ISP, далее выполнял просто переход по ссылке 
  [https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕН/setwebhook?url=URL](https://api.telegram.org/bot%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D/setwebhook?url=URL)
- Загрузкой самоподписанного сертификата [OpenSSL / Let's Encrypt]
  `curl -F "url=URL" -F "certificate=@cert.pem" "https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕН/setwebhook"`

Пробовал даже на разных доменах.
Но все мои попытки приводили лишь к одному...

```
{
 "ok": true,
 "result": {
  "url": "URL",
  "has_custom_certificate": false,
  "pending_update_count": 35,
  "last_error_date": 1516221264,
  "last_error_message": "SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}",
  "max_connections": 40
 }
}
```

Comment: Браузер при переходе по url вебхука показывает, что подключение защищено? Если нажать на просмотр защищенности подключения - нет ли там проблем?

Answer (score 0):

если сертификат от Let's Encrypt, тогда без @ перед именем ключа:

```
curl -F "url=https://www.domain.ru" -F "certificate=cert.pem" 
"https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕН/setwebhook"
```